# Must an Android View id be unique?

Tags: android, view, android-viewpager

This question rests on, and extends, previous questions on the same topic.

I refer particularly to page 203 of "Android Programming Big Nerd...".  This attractive and useful book devotes much of that page to explaining that you *must* use XML for the id.

In fact that seems not to be the case.  Being one of the 'more curious' addressed (though not on this topic) in special sections throughout the book, I found that you had to have an id, but that 1, 37, 42, 99, and I expect many others would do as well as the R-ensured-unique one recommended.

I am quite bemused at the complexity of the ViewPager topic (and the fact that it is only in the support library...) and should welcome an authoritative statement on the simple view id case.

I am raising the matter here since the Big Nerd forums seem a bit moribund, and I dare say Bill & Brian drop in here from time to time.

Comment: you should read the faq of stackoverflow

Comment: And so should we all, my dear fellow.  Many thanks?

Answer (score 3):

No it doesn't need to be unique but it's best to try keep unique names in a single xml file or else findViewById will run into problems

a_layout.xml

```
<View android:id="@+id/name" .../>
<View android:id="@+id/name" .../>
```

findViewById wont know if you want the first or second. but if they are in separate files

a_layout.xml

```
<View android:id="@+id/name" .../>
```

b_layout.xml

```
<View android:id="@+id/name" .../>
```

There's no conflict, project wide duplicates are ok, but could cause issue in the same xml

Answer (score 0):

No, an id does not have to be unique at all not even within the same layout.

However the behaviour of functions like `findViewById()` is not defined for conflicting ids, nor is layout behavior defined so it is definitely better to keep them unique.

Answer (score -1):

For the same type view , you should have unique ID. But for the different type view, you can have the same id . E.X.

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/name1" .../>
<TextView android:id="@+id/name2" .../>
```

Above should have unique ID.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/name" .../>
<TextView android:id="@+id/name" .../>
```

But for this situation, you can have the same ID.